# Get Max value and another column from same row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I return max value and the date from the following table?

```
declare @t1 table 
(
    id int,
    value int,
    date date
)

insert into @t1
select 1, 100, '2017-01-02'
union
select 1, 200, '2017-01-03'
union
select 1, 300, '2017-01-04'
union
select 2, 400, '2017-02-02'
union
select 2, 500, '2017-02-03'
union
select 2, 600, '2017-02-04'

select id, max(value) from @t1 group by id
```

The following returns max value, but I also need the date from that max value. In this case, it would be `300, '2017-01-04'` and `600, '2017-02-04'`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for the max Value on each date, or in each group? Or just the single Max Value and the associated date?

Comment: The max value and its associated date.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to find all data from the row with the MAX(value) for each ID. Use partitioning:

```
SELECT id, value, date
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) AS i, *
          FROM @t1
       ) parts
 WHERE i = 1
```

Of course, you're going to have a problem with all of these answers if you have duplicate MAX(value)s for an id. But you can address that here by changing the partition ordering.

For instance, to find the most recent row with the MAX(value), simply add `date DESC` to the PARTITION clause:

```
SELECT id, value, date
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC, date DESC) AS i, *
          FROM @t1
       ) parts
 WHERE i = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Join your table to the query that you have by `id` and select whatever fields you want:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT  Name, MAX(value) value
            FROM t1
            GROUP BY id) b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to get your max value per ID then join to your original table to get the data fields you want.

```
;WITH grp AS (SELECT id, MAX(value) max_val FROM @t1 GROUP BY id) 
SELECT t.* FROM @t1 t JOIN grp ON t.id = grp.id AND t.value = grp.max_val
```

The leading semicolon is optional, but best practice since CTEs require any previous SQL statements to be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to get the maximum value in your table and it's associated date:

```
SELECT value
    ,Date
FROM @t1
where value in (
    select max(value)
    from @T1 
)
```